# c macro decimal to string

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define TMP4(x) #x
#define TMP3(x) TMP4(x)

const char tmp[] = TMP3(10+20);
```

Result =>  tmp => "10+20"

How can I change it like below.

tmp =>  "30"

Comment: Simply don't use the "stringify" operator.

Comment: @Gereon Then initializing of `tmp` won't work.

Comment: No, I don't think it is possible. The preprocessor *can* perform arithmetic, but only to use its results by itself (that is to compare with other constants and such)

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the `#` operator will turn the whole passed macro parameter into a string, so it isn't very helpful.

Common sense would therefore instead encourage code such as:

```
const char tmp[] = "30"; // 10+20
```

If that isn't an option, then you'll have to resort to very ugly and very specific pre-processor tricks. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ADDIFY(CH1, CH2) (CH1 + CH2 - '0')
#define ADD_STRINGIFY(a,b) { ADDIFY(#a[0], #b[0]), ADDIFY(#a[1], #b[1]), '\0' }

int main(void)
{
  const char tmp[] = ADD_STRINGIFY(11, 22);
  puts(tmp);
}
```

This is a very crude version that could be refined in many ways. As it stands, it only works with 2 numbers, each exactly 2 digits long. It generates an array initializer list of characters. `#a[0]` gives the first character in the string `"11"` If you add that with the first character in the string `"22"` and subtract `'0'`, you get the character `'3'`.